# Why child_process.spawn prevents parent exit?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I wrote a python script containing infinite loop (called it test.py).

And then I run it using spawn in nodeJS.

Here is the content of the nodejs Script:

```
const {spawn} = require("child_process")
spawn("python", ["test.py"], { encoding: 'utf8'});
```

Why this doesn't exit immediately?

Does the spawn put something in the Event Table or Poll Queue?